# Tsung: Can we use voice chat, file transfer in tsung by jabber plugin

Tags: chat, file-transfer, voice, tsung

Can we pass voice chat and file transfer through jabber plugin in tsung. 
How can i create actual chatting load in a mobile messaging app like whats app.

[I've created a session in tsung to xmpp server via jabber plug in. In same session I passed online and offline chat through chat tag. But didn't find any way to create the load for Voice Chat / File Transfer]

Thanks